# Is it possible to open two different forms in page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have 2 nested forms such that Estates has Revenue and Estates has Expense, and current form signature looks like for expense "`<%= form_for [@estate,@expense] do |f| %>`" and for revenue "`<%= form_for [@estate,@revenue] do |f| %>`". My routes for these are

```
resources :estates do

    resources :revenues

    resources :expenses

    resources :net_profits

  end
```

Now can I open revenue and expense form on the same page on click of 1 new button and 1 submit button for both these forms ?

Comment: They should be nested forms of `Estate`, what's the issue?

Comment: currently what I have is, I have to open revenue and expense forms separately on there own page to create new revenue and expense, But I want them to open on the same page and I want them to have 1 single submit button for them

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need into your model `Estate` the following:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :revenue
accepts_nested_attributes_for :expense
```

Then you can just generate it with a `form_for` like this:

```
= form_for(@estate, :url => {:action=>'update'}) do |f|
  = f.fields_for :revenue do |r|
    # revenue fields here, for example:
    = r.text_field :name
  = f.fields_for :expense do |e|
    # expense fields here, for example:
    = e.text_field :name
```

This is an example with [HAML](http://haml.info/) markup and for an update of the object. You could however modify it for object generation (create).

Comment: How will I write the controller for this ? because I created these forms using scaffold. Is it possible to write both forms in the partials of either of the scaffold and include the controller of 1 form into another ?